# How to attach a library to a page controller that returns a plain Symfony response?

Tags: 8, page-controller

I created a custom module with a page controller that returns a Symfony response (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response). The thing is I don't want to render my custom theme in this controller, just the theme_base template in this module.

```
$build = array(
  'page' => array(
    '#theme' => 'theme_base',
    '#content' => $content,
    '#owner' => $owner,
    '#cache' => [
      'max-age' => 0,
    ],
    '#attached' => array(
      'library' => array(
        'my_module/library_name',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent($html);

return $response;
```

I tried attaching the module library to $build, or including it directly in Twig template but this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas why this is not working? Or is there maybe another way I could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are displaying it in a page in drupal site itself then you don't need to use `renderRoot()`. The libraries will be attached since drupal renders the renderable array `$build` that you return.

Comment: I don't want to display it in a page. I would like to have it completely separate, only with whatever I put in my #theme_base template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rendering of `$build` the attachments have bubbled up to `$build['#attached']` and you can add them to a response, which implements `AttachmentsInterface`, for example an HtmlResponse:

```
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
$response = new HtmlResponse();
$response->setContent($html);
$response->setAttachments($build['#attached']);
return $response;
```

To place the libraries on the page you have to enclose the page in an `html` render element

```
$build = [
  '#type' => 'html',
  'page' => [
     // content with attached libraries  
  ],
];
```

or implement the placeholders where the attachment will end up in a custom template, see [template_preprocess_html()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.5.x).

Comment: I tried this, but now I get an error and still no attachments: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
AssertionError: assert(is_string($chunk) || $chunk instanceof HtmlResponse) in assert() (line 259 of core/modules/big_pipe/src/Render/BigPipe.php).
assert(, 'assert(is_string($chunk) || $chunk instanceof HtmlResponse)') (Line: 259)"

Comment: The error was my mistake, sorry. Disregard the above comment. But I'm still not getting attachments.

Comment: I think you need to enclose the page in an `html` render element to attach libraries: `$build = ['#type' => 'html', 'page' => [... ]];`

Comment: This is it, thank you! Can you update you answer so I can accept it?